# How to prevent user from exiting form if there is an error in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi all i want to make sure if there is an  error the user will not be allowed to exit the form
Which line of is it. I think it might be the one below but i am not sure where to place it

```
    e.cancel
```

Comment: disable close button.

Comment: how and which event to place it in???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `FormClosing` event handler:

```
e.Cancel = True
```